# Task.WhenAll didn't complete all tasks; it returns on completion of first task

Tags: vb.net, async-await, task-parallel-library

`Task.WhenAll` returns on completion of first task. I am just looping records and adding it to `taskList` then await `Task.WhenAll` but while debugging I found it returns to main function after completion of first task. Please check my `TrackPackages` function:

```
Public Async Function TrackPackages(ByVal trackingNos As String) As Task(Of String)

    Dim trackResponseXml As String = String.Empty
    Dim skipNos As Integer = 0
    Dim takeNos As Integer = 10
    Dim strResponses As String = String.Empty
    Dim taskList As List(Of Task(Of String)) = New List(Of Task(Of String))()

    If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(trackingNos) Then
        Dim totalTrackingNos As List(Of String) = trackingNos.Split(","c).ToList()
        skipNos = 0
        'Dim totallparalleltask = (totalTrackingNos.Count / 35)
        'For var = 0 To totallparalleltask
        While skipNos < totalTrackingNos.Count
            Dim trackingNoArray = totalTrackingNos.Skip(skipNos).Take(takeNos).ToList()
            taskList.Add(Task.Run(Function() GetTrackResponseXML(trackingNoArray)))

            skipNos = skipNos + 10
        End While
        'Next var
        Dim lastindex As Integer = 0

        'Here is issue with task.whenall it returns on completion of first task
        Dim alltaskstring = Await Task.WhenAll(taskList.ToArray)

        If (Task.WhenAll(taskList).IsCompleted) Then
            'Dim abcsdsd As String = Await GetTrackResponseString(item, trackResponseXml)
            Return trackResponseXml
        End If
    End If

End Function
```

It should complete all tasks from `Task.WhenAll(taskList)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not properly distinguishing between `WaitAll` and `WhenAll`.  `WhenAll` is itself awaitable while `WaitAll` is not.  You either want this:

```
If Task.WaitAll(taskList) Then
    'All tasks completed.
```

or this:

```
Await Task.WhenAll(taskList)

'All tasks completed.
```

You should read the documentation for those methods.  You should ALWAYS read the relevant documentation when something doesn't work as you expect.  Sites like this are a last resort, not a first option.

EDIT:

I just realised that you are awaiting `Task.WhenAll` but then you ignore that result and call `Task.WhenAll` again without awaiting it.  I saw the second call first and didn't look any further to notice the first call.  I'll provide an example that should hopefully clear things up.

EDIT:

Here's an example of how to call `WhenAll`.  This code requires a Windows Form with a `Button` and a `TextBox` with `Multiline` set to `True`.  The code kicks off 10 tasks that return a `String` and waits for them to complete by calling `WhenAll` and awaiting it.  When all tasks have completed, `WhenAll` returns an array containing the result of each individual task.

```
Private rng As New Random

Private Async Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim tasks As New List(Of Task(Of String))

    For i = 1 To 10
        tasks.Add(GetTimeStringAsync(i))
    Next

    'Wait for all tasks to complete and aggregate the results.
    Dim results = Await Task.WhenAll(tasks)

    'Use the aggregated results.
    TextBox1.Lines = results
End Sub

Private Async Function GetTimeStringAsync(number As Integer) As Task(Of String)
    'Get the current time as text after a random delay of between 2 and 10 seconds.
    Return Await Task.Run(Async Function()
                              Await Task.Delay(rng.Next(2000, 10000))

                              Return $"{number}: {Date.Now:HH:mm:ss.fffff}"
                          End Function)
End Function
```

Note that if the task methods are type `Task(Of T)` then the return type of `WhenAll` is `Task(Of T())`.  In your case and mine, this means that awaiting `WhenAll` produces a `String` array.